# Spring-data-neo4j + @Query throws PropertyReferenceException

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have following repository for my `Domain` class:

```
public interface IDomainRepository extends GraphRepository<Domain>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<Domain>{
    //cause of error
    @Query("MATCH n WHERE id(n) = {0} SET n :{1}")
    public void attachLabel(Long id, String label);

}
```

From `GraphManager` (a service, which is using IDomainRepository) i'm calling `attachLabel` as following:

```
@Transactional
    public void attachLabel(Domain domain, String label){
        domainRepository.attachLabel(domain.getId(), label);
    }
```

And here is my test case, for `attachLabel` method:

```
@Test
    public void attachLabelSuccess(){

        Domain domain = new Domain();
        domain.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        domain.setDescription("xyz");

        domain = graphManager.create(domain);
        graphManager.attachLabel(domain, "DummyLabel");

        Domain d1 = domainRepository.findOne(domain.getId());

        //Should have [Domain, DummyLabel]
        Assert.assertEquals(2, d1.getLabels().size());
    }
```

I get the following exception, when I run the test it fails at loading ApplicationContext:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'IDomainRepository': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
No property attach found for type Domain!
...
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
No property attach found for type Domain!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
```

Seems that SDN is somehow trying to map first part of `attachLabel` (attach) to property of `Domain` class. I've tried to rename the method, but the error still appears.

Configuration: Sprind-Data-Neo4j version 3.1.1.RELEASE, neo4j version 2.1.2.

**FIXED**
The problem was, that I accidentally used @Query annotation from mongodb namespace instead od neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update labels with parameters in Cypher. That's unfortunately not possible.

So you'd have to construct the query and run it via the neo4jTemplate.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and already solved it in the same way you suggested. I also noticed that there is @Labels annotation (planned) for managing labels. When is it going to be supported?